# Minitest plugins (ie. minitest/pride) not working after installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have two Ruby projects (1 Rails, 1 vanilla). Both using Ruby 3.0.3. In my Ruby project (before bundling my Rails one), Minitest::Pride is loaded and works when running `rake test`. But, after bundling the Rails project, I'm back to old red/green colors for `rake test` in the Ruby project.

Here's the file structure (for simplicity's sake, I'm stripping the Rails project down to just a Gemfile, which I can reproduce this error with on a clean Ruby Rbenv install):

```
ruby-project/
  -- test/
    -- example_test.rb
    -- test_helper.rb
  Gemfile
  Rakefile
rails-project/
  -- Gemfile
```

ruby-project/test/example_test.rb:

```
require "test_helper"

class ExampleTest < Minitest::Test
  25.times do |i|
    define_method "test_success#{i}" do
      assert true
    end
  end
end
```

ruby-project/test/test_helper:

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/pride"
```

ruby-project/Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rake"
gem "minitest"
```

ruby-project/Rakefile:

```
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs = %w(lib test)
  t.pattern = "test/**/*_test.rb"
end

task :default => :test
```

**rails-project**/Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "3.0.3"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3"
```

**Steps to Reproduce** (with rbenv already installed):

1. Build two projects like the ones above
2. `rbenv install 3.0.3`
3. From ruby-project dir: `bundle`
4. From ruby-project dir: `rake test` (Minitest::Pride plugin loaded)
5. From rails-project dir: `bundle`
6. From ruby-project dir: `rake test` (Minitest::Pride plugin NOT loaded)

**Things I have tried**:

1. locking Minitest to the exact same version for both projects (5.16.3 and 5.17.0)
2. locking Rails to 7.0.3.1 and 7.0.4.2
3. Bundling the Rails project first

I'm running on a M1 Mac, but I'm not sure this matters. Interestingly, `rails test` in a real Rails project WILL load Minitest::Pride.

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix?

**UPDATE**

Running `bundle exec rake test` from the Ruby project fixes the issue. But I'd still love to know why. Especially when both projects are using the same version of the rake and minitest gems.

Comment: I might miss something, but from the files you shared, it feels to me like you didn't add `minitext` to the Rails' project `Gemfile` nor required `minitest/pride` in its `rails_helper` or `test_helper` file. Because both projects are independent of each other, pride needs basically the same setup in the Rails project than in the Ruby project.

Comment: Yeah it actually doesn't matter. Minitest gets bundled with Rails. It's a dependency (>= 5.1) of activesupport (7.0.4.2/7.0.3.1, which is a dependency of rails). But the point is that after bundling Rails, the Minitest installed for the Ruby project doesn't work as designed anymore.

Comment: But, even specifying the exact same Minitest version that in the Rails project that was used in the Ruby project still causes the problem.